# Django static files not loading or not working?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

I have been trying to implement a way to upload multiple images using JQuery. For some reason, my js file is not being called when I click the upload photos button.

Whenever I click the upload photos button nothing happens.

UPDATE: I think my js files aren't loading and have issues as shown in the browser console

My codes are below:

I am not sure if am doing something wrong with my create_posts function in the views or..

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.http import JsonResponse

from .models import Projects, P_Images
from .forms import ProjectsForm, P_ImageForm
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

# Create your views here.
# Function to create projects



def create_projects(request):
    #P_ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(P_Images,form=P_ImageForm, extra=3)
    # Special case if the request method is not POST

    #if request.method == 'POST':
        project_form = ProjectsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        p_photos = P_ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        # Checks if the form is valid before save
        if project_form.is_valid() and p_formset.is_valid():
            instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            p_photos.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': p_photos.file.name, 'url': p_photos.file.url}


        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        #    print(project_form.errors, p_formset.errors)
        #return JsonResponse(data)
        context = { 
        'project_form': project_form,
        'p_photos': p_photos,
        }
        return render(request, 'projects/test2.html', context)


# Function to retrieve all different projects
def retrieve_projects(request):
    # Retrieves objects based on latest publish date
    projects_list = Projects.objects.all().order_by("-publish_date")
    context = {
        'projects_list': projects_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html', context)

# Function to update projects
def update_projects(request, slug):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Projects, slug=slug)
    project_form = ProjectsForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)

    # Update_date becomes the latest time
    if project_form.is_valid():
        project_form.save()
        return redirect('retrieve_projects')
    context = {
        'instance': instance,
        'project_form': project_form
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/forms.html', context)

# Function to delete projects chosen
def delete_projects(request, slug):
    Projects.objects.filter(slug=slug).delete()
    return redirect('retrieve_projects')

# Function to show details of project using the ids
def details_of_project(request, slug):
    # Will raise 404 if there is not such id
    project_details = get_object_or_404(Projects, slug=slug)
    context = {
        'project_details': project_details,
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/posts.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path, include
from . import views

# urls for projects page
app_name = 'p_photos'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.retrieve_projects, name="retrieve_projects"),
    re_path(r'^create/$', views.create_projects, name="create_projects"),
    re_path(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.details_of_project, name="details_of_project"),
    re_path(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/update/$', views.update_projects, name="update_projects"),
    re_path(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', views.delete_projects, name="delete_projects"),
]
```

Am I doing something wrong with my html in terms of loading static files?

test2.html

```
{% extends "projects/test.html" %}

{% block javascript %}
{% load static %}

{# JQUERY FILE UPLOAD SCRIPTS #}
<script src="{% static 'projects/js/jquery-file-upload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'projects/js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'projects/js/jquery-file-upload/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>

{# PHOTOS PAGE SCRIPTS #}
<script src="{% static 'projects/js/basic-upload.js' %}"></script>

{# 1. BUTTON TO TRIGGER THE ACTION #}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></span> Upload photos
</button>

{# 2. FILE INPUT TO BE USED BY THE PLUG-IN #}
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple
       style="display: none;"
       data-url="{% url 'p_photos:create_projects' %}"
       data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>

{# 3. TABLE TO DISPLAY THE UPLOADED PHOTOS #}
<table id="gallery" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Photo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for p_photo in p_photos %}
      <tr>
        <td><a href="{{ p_photo.file.url }}">{{ p_photo.file.name }}</a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

    <h1>hahahaha</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

test.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}Photos Library - Simple is Better Than Complex{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    {% block javascript %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

basic-upload.js

```
$(function () {
    /* 1. OPEN THE FILE EXPLORER WINDOW */
    $(".js-upload-photos").click(function () {
      $("#fileupload").click();
    });

    /* 2. INITIALIZE THE FILE UPLOAD COMPONENT */
    $("#fileupload").fileupload({
      dataType: 'json',
      done: function (e, data) {  /* 3. PROCESS THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER */
        if (data.result.is_valid) {
          $("#gallery tbody").prepend(
            "<tr><td><a href='" + data.result.url + "'>" + data.result.name + "</a></td></tr>"
          )
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

This is how my static setup looks like in my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..', 'static'),
)
```

Browser Console Error

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8000/static/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js”. create:20
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8000/static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js”. create:21
[Show/hide message details.] ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.ui.widget.js:18:5
[Show/hide message details.] TypeError: $ is undefined jquery.iframe-transport.js:49:5
[Show/hide message details.] TypeError: $ is undefined jquery.fileupload.js:38:5
[Show/hide message details.] ReferenceError: $ is not defined basic-upload.js:1:1
```

Comment: Is debug set to true in your settings.py?

Comment: @Taylor Yes it is

Comment: Make sure that you have cleared the caches and open the browser console. If there is any error in your javascript, it might appear there.

Comment: @Ramtin I checked the browser console and it seems like there are problems loading my js files. I am not sure why some stuff are not defined tho. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Ramtin I fixed! Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove STATIC_ROOT, this should only be used if you are collecting static files. Also make sure your javascript is in a folder called static

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: I finally fixed it! Thanks for your help!